# MySQL SQL Select Query with Multiple Sub-Selects

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

OK, so this one has had me ripping my hair out for hours.  I feel like there is something obvious I am overlooking.

I have 2 tables,  **service** and **brand**

```
service
-------
id
brand

brand
-----
id
brandName
```

So service.brand can be any of these:

```
Blank 
"Other" 
Integer (matches brand.id) 
String (matches brand.brandName)
String (Not Blank, Not Other, Not brand.brandName)
```

I'm trying to write a query that will pull up the correct brandname from the brand table, and if the value of service.brand is not in brand.id or brand.brandName,  then display whatever is there.

So far I got everything working except it wouldn't pull up the record if service.brand was Not Blank, Not Other, Not in brand.id, Not in brand.brandName. (which I'm calling OtherThanOther from here on out).

Now my latest attempt pulls up mostly correct, but the OtherThanOther field gets pulled up many times,  like if total records is 40,  OtherThanOther is the same record almost 20 times.  HELP!

My latest attempt..

```
select 
    s.*, b.brandName as bname 
from 
    service s, brand b 
where 
    s.brand = b.brandName 
or 
    s.brand = b.id 
or 
    s.brand = 'Other' 
or 
    s.brand = ''
or
    (       
        s.brand not in (select brandName from brand)
        and
        s.brand not in (select id from brand)
        and
        s.brand != 'Other'
        and
        s.brand != ''
    )
```

Sample Table Data

```
service
-------
1 5
2 Dell
3 SomeRandom
4 
5 Other

brand
-----

1 HP
2 Gateway
3 Dell
4 Compaq
5 Toshiba
```

my query results..

```
(service.id, service.brand, brand.id, brand.brandName, bname)
-------------------------------------------------------------
1 5 5 Toshiba Toshiba
2 Dell 3 Dell Dell
3 SomeRandom, brand.id, brand.brandName, brand.brandName
3 SomeRandom, brand.id, brand.brandName, brand.brandName
3 SomeRandom, brand.id, brand.brandName, brand.brandName
3 SomeRandom, brand.id, brand.brandName, brand.brandName
3 SomeRandom, brand.id, brand.brandName, brand.brandName
4 '', null, null, null
5 Other, null, null, null
```

I need it to just pull SomeRandom once, group by won't work because there may be multiple fields with the same value as SomeRandom.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: join two tables and Use CASE

Comment: Can you post an answer of how that would work?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if that will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    s.*, 
    CASE 
      WHEN b_id.brandName IS NOT NULL THEN b_id.brandName
      WHEN b.brandName IS NOT NULL THEN b.brandName
      ELSE s.brand 
    END as bname 
from 
    service s
LEFT JOIN brand b_id 
ON  CAST(s.brand AS UNSIGNED) = b_id.id
LEFT JOIN brand b
ON  s.brand = b.brandName
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what 'enter code here' means in your answer.

Comment: :-) I have no idea either. @NotoriousPet0 check update. just remove that from query :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old style `inner join`:

```
from service s, brand b 
where s.brand = b.brandName or ...
```

More clearly written like:

```
from service s
inner join brand b on s.brand = b.brandName or ...
```

In the newer form, the problem immediately stands out.  An `inner join` filters out unmatched rows.  Use a `left join` instead:

```
from service s
left join brand b on s.brand = b.brandName or ...
```

Now you'll get all services, even if no matching row was found in the `brand` table.

Comment: Inner and Left join pull up the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You should `JOIN` 2 tables with multiple conditions. Something like this:

```
SELECT s.*, b.brandName AS bname
FROM service AS s
INNER JOIN brand AS b
ON s.brand = b.brandName OR 
   s.brand = b.id OR 
   s.brand = 'Other' OR 
   s.brand = '' OR  
   (s.brand NOT IN (SELECT brandName FROM brand) AND
   s.brand NOT IN (SELECT id FROM brand) AND 
   s.brand != 'Other' AND
   s.brand != '')
```

Comment: It throws any errors? Edited, try to use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Try with INNER JOIN, If it not works I will make edit

Answer (score 0):

First thing - use JOIN!

```
select s.*, b.brandName as bname 
from service s 
    LEFT JOIN brand b ON s.brand = b.brandName or s.brand = b.id
```

Then you can add your sensemaking conditions - for example `WHERE NOT s.brand IS NULL`

These condotions of you are leading to the result in which your table rows are multiplied with each other:

```
s.brand = 'Other' 
or 
    s.brand = ''
or
     (       
        s.brand not in (select brandName from brand)
        and
        s.brand not in (select id from brand)
        and
        s.brand != 'Other'
        and
        s.brand != ''
    )
```

Comment: When this "ON s.brand = b.brandName or s.brand = b.id" doesn't have a match,  it gives me a record for every entry in the brand table.  so if 17 different records in brand table,  then I get 17 dupes  (well, brandname ends up as brand.brandName for the row so its 17 different values, but its' all on the same initial service table record)

Comment: i told you to then add a sensemaking condition. btw this wont give you every record from brand table. left join gives you every record from service and only matching from brand.

Comment: I did everything just like you told me.   Left join wont' work then based on what you are saying because sometimes it won't be in brand table.

Comment: you're missing the basically understanding for SQL. if you want more help provide an sql fiddle with your data structure and data